# how to inject dependency in module from other js file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to inject a dependency for example ngMessages into my module but i want this injection from other file (from my validation.js file). then how can i do this,
for clear understanding i am providing a dummy example below

> app.js code

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']); //i don't want to inject here
```

> validation.js code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.$inject = ['ngMessages'];       //i try like this but not happen
```

Comment: second parameter accepts an array of strings, just initialise it (above) as `var array = ['ngMessages']` and pass it as `angular.module('myApp', array);`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey when use this type of injecting, will it create new model or not?

Comment: I believe `angular.module('myApp')` would try to find an existing module named *myApp* (and then reference it), and `angular.module('myApp', [])` would create a new module (and then bootstrap it). So you need an array as the second parameter, and I don't think you can inject something separately

Comment: @AlekseySolovey okay, you mean that i create an module with [ ] this and later wherever i want inject or add dependency then use array variable. right or wrong

Comment: no, in your case it would be `['ngMessages']`, or just `array` (some global variable, e.g. `var array = ['ngMessages']`), but you cannot leave the second parameter for your module blank

Comment: @AlekseySolovey i am confused now , can you please provide me an example of what you want to say

Comment: my first comment was an example

Comment: @AlekseySolovey can you please provide your comment as an answer of my question. and also an example with my code. please

Answer (score 0):

My understanding from your question is :
You have ngMessages injected in validation.js code and you want to use ngMessages functionality inside app.js code.

You can `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);` inside validation.js code 
And can just use like `angular.module('myApp');`inside app.js code. And use the ngMessages functionality.

Please find the plunker link below :
[Angular Ui Router Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/KUzxOnlY1wSEqLzZPa5y?p=preview)

There, I have injected 'ui-router' inside script.js and used the functionality inside config.js without injecting ui-router again.

Hope this help.

Comment: if you say i can repeat my question for you

Comment: My bad .Please it will be better.

Comment: okay then, i repeat my question. My question is that is it possible to inject dependency in module from other file. if the module is created already like this angular.module('myApp', [ ]); and this statement create myApp module. then in validation file i want to add dependency in myApp name ngMessages, or any other file like also want to add ngMaterial dependency from other. is it possible?

Comment: May be the approach should be create a new module (say myApp1 ) in validation.js , have your ngMessages dependency injection in myApp1. Then have the myApp1 injected into myApp. Let me know what you think about this approach.

Comment: And as far as injecting some dependency on the same module after creation using / inside [] , I don't think it is possible as if angular will find a module with [] it will create a new module there as per my understanding